# C# FileUpload SaveAs Casing

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using a `FileUpload` control and have a question about the `SaveAs method`.  If a file is uploaded that exists I know it will overwrite it, but if the casing is different on the name of the file, does it use the existing filename or the new one.

**example**

> if I have a file named TEST.txt on the server and a new upload named
>   test.txt comes in, which name would be used?

Comment: what does `casing` mean..

Comment: @Rahul - upper case / lower case.

Comment: Yep, sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer depends on how the OS behaves.

With a Windows OS, the file will be overwritten. Essentially, as far as Windows is concerned, filenames are case insensitive, at least for the purpose of identifying them. Windows will also use the new filename if overwritten (try it yourself - copy a file with a different case into a folder and see what comes up), though older versions of the OS used the original filename (XP did so).

On a Linux OS a new file will be created. Linux/Unix/iOS (and pretty much all Unix variants) treat files with different casing as different files.

Comment: It's a Windows server and I know it will be overwritten, but not sure if it will retain the casing of the original file or the new file.

Comment: @katastraphi - If you don't specifically delete it, the original will be overwritten, though older versions would have retained the original.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this isn't exactly answering the question, but I think it would be safer not to make any assumptions as to what filename will be used after the replacement.

So I recommend that you save the uploaded files only in lower case, that way if you switch servers (OSes) you'll have your back covered and it will save you some debugging.

Comment: While I agree we should be consistent, the lead developer wants to be able to tell if a user has updated a document. When they originally create it it will be all uppercase and then an edit will move it to lowercase.  When they are uploaded they are scanned and then moved to a different folder. If they edit before it is scanned we needed to know which file name would be used.

Comment: I think you guys look at this the wrong way, but this is just my opinion. For the use case you've described in the above comment I'd create a hash (md5 is fast these days) of the file contents every time it is uploaded, if the second (or any of the later in case there were multiple updates) hash is different from the first (or the last in case there were multiple updates), you'll know the file is changed.

Comment: Unfortunately, for the way the system is set up this wouldn't work without making a lot of changes.  I had no hand it setting this up so I'm just trying to make sure what's there works how the client wants it to.